# Apache commons validator, bean properties to validate should all be string?

Tags: java, validation, jakarta-ee, servlets, apache-commons

I was working on apache commons validator latest. Problem explained below.

My Bean is having 2 properties fullName (String) & age (int). Validation "required" on both but age needed to be checked for "integer" as well.

```
bean.setFullName("Tester"); -----> Will Pass
bean.setAge("Too Old"); ---> "required Pass but "integer" Fail.

results = validator.validate();
```

**Note:** Above is possible if age property is String but its not and setAge won't accept String value and throw exception before reaching validator.validate().

Validation should be checked before we set the bean. In above situation I need to make all properties string than in validation.xml check for integer/condition.

***How I work with this when my age property is Integer. little confused. Handle bean with date, integer etc?***

Comment: can you give some details on the exception you see?

Comment: Note that there is a http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/validator/example/ValidateExample.java.html that does what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: @pd40, before posting here I googled few days and looked all validator examples could find. All the examples use properties as Strings. Not a single example with any other type suppose integer. Its easy to use properties as String and than validate with apache validator. One Question: All your bean properties are String (Age, Date of Birth, Currency etc) ?

Comment: @pd40, bean.setAge("Too Old"); where Age is integer property and passing "Too Old" won't allow it to set age property. I want properties to be other than String like Age as Integer than call results = validator.validate();. For validator to work I only can have String properties. Hope you get my point.

Comment: @nickname don't work if the person hasn't commented before on the current post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Bean is having 2 properties fullName (String) & age (int). Validation "required" on both **but age needed to be checked for "integer" as well**.

If your domain class declares `age` already to be an `int` then you have two options

1. Check the data before you call setAge(int a) and you can use the [IntegerValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/IntegerValidator.html)
2. Provide a overloaded method setAge(String a) which internall uses [IntegerValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/IntegerValidator.html)

**My recommendation**

commons-validator only works on strings (if you want your entire bean to be validated at once) and isn't a fit for your scenario. I suggest you dump that in favor of the standard [JSR 303](http://java.dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-and-jsr-303). It is rich in functionality and has a two very good implementations:

1. [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html)
2. [Apache BVAL](http://bval.apache.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Very informative. I have 2 questions. I am using Servlet/JSP project as noob (no framework). What should be the preferred way of validation (use in the development. Just suggestion)?. Someone suggested me BeanUtils. Mapping properties? . Any idea.

Comment: I still suggest JSR 303. It can be used standalone independent of any framework. Usage is simple. Post more questions if you need help and I will try to help.

Comment: Give me sometime to look into your solutions and will post if any question. I will award you bounty before the days end. Do you think BeanUtils. Mapping properties can be the solution for my with apache commons validator with integer property?